# PDO database connection issue in MAMP – Keeps creating new databases

Tags: php, pdo

For some reason, this code always returns “Connected to Database” even when I try to test the, try catch block and break the connection. When I change the name of the database to test the exception, it just creates a new database. 
Any ideas?

```
<?php
try{
$db = new PDO ("sqlite:".__DIR__."/database.db"); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
echo "Connected to Database";
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it will always output Connected to Database not returns. You should examine/ include the database.db

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is expected behavior with pdo_sqlite: if you provide a path to a database that doesn't exist, and PHP is able to write to files in the directory of that path, it will simply create the database under the filename you've provided.

If you want to test the case where the file isn't writable, you can change file permissions such that the user that PHP runs as doesn't have write access.

Answer (score -1):

Because `echo "Connected to Database";` is not within the `try` brackets, it will always echo that.

Try this.

```php
<?php
try{
    $db = new PDO ("sqlite:".__DIR__."/database.db"); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected to Database";
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
?>
```